# Special characters æøå in Table

Tags: tables, characters, scandinavian-letters

I have the problem that whenever I set the preamble right so that I can use the characters æ ø å in the text of the document with no problem, the special characters in tables that are entered look weird. Like in the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[english, norsk]{babel}  
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  

\begin{document}  

\section{Introduction}

æ

ø

å

\begin{table}
\caption[c]{æ ø å}
\begin{tabular}{l r r r r r r r r }
\hline
\input{testtable.tex}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table looks like this:

```
\hline  
åÅå   &       0.875&        3192 \\  
æÆæ &      0.0793&        3192 \\   
øØø &       30.61&        1671 \\  
\hline
```

Including

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in the preamble makes the characters in the table look fine, but then texworks can't compile due to the special characters used in the text of the article.
Anyone understand why?

Thanks!
Sara

Edit:

[image: Output 1]

The image above is what my output looks like when I do not include the
% !TeX encoding = utf8
suggested by @Sveinung.

[image: Output 2]

The image above shows how it looks when I do include that line: Now also the characters in the text are wrong.

My settings look like this:

[image]

I have encoded both the main file and the input file to UTF-8 using Notepad.

Comment: Are you sure the document is actually being saved as UTF8?

Comment: What are the contents of `TABLEWITHÆØÅ.tex`?  Can you save that file using only ascii in the filename?  The filename is a different problem than getting the characters to appear in the output document.  Both problems are unrelated to using a table.

Comment: @daleif: How can I see if the document is being saved as UTF8?

Comment: @Teepeemm: It's not the table's title that is the problem. I have added its content now, and given it a different name. For some reason it is displayed with only a single \ at the end of each line, but there are two. The table compiles fine, it's just that the characters in it look weird.

Comment: Your files seems to have different encodings: the main file is 8bit, the table utf8. You should ensure that every file has the same encoding - utf8 is today the standard. Try to create a new main file in utf8 and then copy and paste the content of your current main file in it, and then use the utf8 option.

Comment: See [Get encoding of a file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13464816/7032505) how to check the encoding of text files under Windows. Under Linux/Unix/... use the command `file` on the command line; `file myfile.tex` will tell you the encoding.

Comment: @Sveinung No, it's not the \hline - my file also compiles (with or without the line), but the characters keep looking weird.

Comment: I have now stored the main file with utf8-encoding, but the problem persists.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, now I have

Comment: @daleif You was correct. The error is the file format.

Comment: @Sveinung If daleif is correct, what do I need to do in addition to encoding the files as UTF-8/checking the settings?

Comment: When you have the file(s) open texworks will show at the bottom the encoding of each file. What does it say?

Comment: @user200771 As Ulrike Fischer says, and ensure that you have the following four packages in your preamble: \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer It says UTF-8 at the bottom on both the main file and the table-file. However, in my original main file it says ISO-8859-1 (due to my "%!TeX encoding = ISO-8859-1" at the top of the document), so I assume I have succeeded in changing the encoding, just not solving the problem.

Comment: @Sveinung Adding your suggestions to the preamble gives the error message "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char  (U+FEFF)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
"

Comment: Stop adding code to your document. Get at first the encoding right.

Comment: Good, now compile first only the main file, without the table, and without inputenc and check if it errors and if looks ok.

Comment: @user200771 Start with a new, empty document in Texworks. Sve that under a new name, and check that it is UTF8. Then add code for a minimal working example. Compile. Add the packages I suggest. Add some text in the document and compile. Now, I have to leave my computer for some hours.

Comment: @Sveinung if the tex system is current \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is not needed.

Comment: I saved both files anew, checking it says UTF-8. Characters in main text only come out fine if \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is in the preamble. But now I get the same error message as above when I try to input the table. I think I'm giving up for now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know, but I do not know if OP has an updated system.

Comment: @user200771 What do you mean by "... getting the same error message as above"?  The "Unicode char is not setup for the use with Latex"? The last one is due to mismatch between the Latex encoding and the file encoding. Typically, you have the % TEX encoding = UT8", but the file is actually still an ANSI-file  or ISO-8859-1 file. You cannot load an ANSI file and save it as an UTF8 file under a new name. You have to create a new empty file, save i a UTF8, and copy and paste the content of the old file to the new file. Then save and compile.

Comment: @user200771 Remember, it is two different encoding that has to match. The file itself has  encoding, and the TeX content in your files has an encoding. I suggest that you download and install Notepad++, open your file in that editor and convert it to UTF8 and save it.

Answer (score 1):

First check that Texworks is set up to use UTF8. Click the `Edit`-menu, choose Preference, and you get a window that shall look like the screenshot below regarding character set.

[image]

Then add to both files:

```
% !TeX encoding = utf8
```

Then ensure that both file actually are saved as UTF8-files. Texworks does not convert an ANSI-file to UTF8 on saving, even if you have set up the UTF8 option. Therefore, you have to copy the file content and paste it into a brand new file, and save it again as UTF8. *Or you can runt the file through a stand alone filter*.

For unknown reasons, the file did not compile as long `\hline` was the first commands in the `testtable.tex`. Therefore, I moved that line to the main file.

[image]

MWE:

```
% !TeX encoding = utf8  %% Add this string
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, norsk]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

æ

ø

å

\begin{table}
\caption[c]{æ ø å}
\begin{tabular}{l r r}
\hline
\input{testtable.tex}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


% testtable.tex
% !TeX encoding = utf8  %% Add this string
%\hline
åÅå & 0.875& 3192 \\
æÆæ & 0.0793& 3192 \\
øØø & 30.61& 1671 \\
%\hline
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work either -- still the same issue.

Comment: I copied your code exactly, still my output has the æøå in the table looking all wrong. Could the issue be with texworks?

Comment: @user200771 Why don't you take a screenshot and add the picture to your question so people can understand exactly what you mean by "all wrong"